# Create a list of item on a single line, then query list to see if item exists, without receiving unchecked conversion warning in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, unchecked

I want a list of things, and then I want to test the list to see if an item exists:

Here is my example snippet:

```
    String[] handToolArray = {"pliers", "screwdriver", "tape measure"}; 
    List<String> handToolList = new ArrayList<String>( Arrays.asList(handToolArray));

    if (handToolList.contains("pliers")){
        System.out.println("I have pliers");
    } else {
        System.out.println("I don't have pliers");
    }
```

In the second line, the Arrays.asList(handToolArray) generates:

```
"Type safety: The expression of type List needs unchecked conversion to conform to Collection<? extends String>"
```

Question:
Is there a better way to create then query the list, that is succinct and does not require unchecked warnings to be suppressed?

Comment: Creating the array or list on a single line is strongly desired.

Comment: I don't get any warnings for that code...

Comment: Have you got an `Arrays` class, that is not the jdk5 `java.util.Arrays`?

Comment: Bingo! I am picking up a non jdk class. Fixing that now!

Answer (score 5):

You can do it without explicitly constructing an array (arrays are still used by varargs).

```
List<String> handToolList = Arrays.asList("pliers", "screwdriver", "tape measure");
```

Comment: Tried that earlier, and this is what I got:

The method asList(Object[]) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, String)

Comment: There is something wrong with your JDK setup. You should not be getting the warning in the first place.

Comment: As noted in previous answer, I am picking up a non-JDK Arrays class. urp!

Comment: This works with the 'correct' import from java.util.Arrays. I like this option!

Comment: This will get an OperationNotSupportedException when you do remove() on the iterator().Because it returns a java.util.Arrays.ArrayList, not java.util.ArrayList.

Comment: @SAN3, there's nothing in the question that requires a `remove`.  However, it's easy to convert to a `java.util.ArrayList` if needed.

Comment: Ya but may be in feature they trying to remove means this exception occurs. But they dont know why. So only i just posted that info.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I do not get the type safety warning, and neither should you. What Java compiler are you using?

Arrays.asList already creates an ArrayList (backed by the original array), so if you do not need a copy, you can just do

```
 List<String> handToolList =  Arrays.asList(handToolArray);
```

Also note that something like Apache Commons Lang ArrayUtils has functions to check if an element exists in an array directly:

```
if (ArrayUtils.exists(handToolArray , "pliers"))
```

Comment: Yes, that is a shorter piece of code (but still generates the unchecked conversion warning.)

Comment: As noted in previous answers, I had a bad import, and unchecked exception went away with import of java.util.Arrays

Answer (score 0):

Note the List interface defines the `indexOf()` method, which you can use to check if something exists:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(handTools);
if(list.indexOf("pliers!") != -1) {
  System.out.println("We have pliers.");
}
else {
  System.out.println("We do not have any pliers.");
}
```

Comment: Why would he prefer that over contains()?